# Ansible become_user results in "Incorrect sudo password" but just using become works

Tags: ansible-2.x, opensuse

```
---
- name: Clone rbenv
  become: yes
  git:
    repo: 'https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git'
    dest: /home/mastodon/.rbenv
```

works just fine

```
---
- name: Clone rbenv
  become: yes
  become_user: mastodon
  git:
    repo: 'https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git'
    dest: /home/mastodon/.rbenv
```

doesn't work, error is 'FAILED! => {"msg": "Incorrect sudo password"}'

ansible_become_pass is set to ansible_user's sudo password

Ansible version: 2.15.3

OS: OpenSUSE

I've tried setting ansible_method, ansible_exe. I expect privilege escalation to make the command run as 'become_user'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my issue was with sudoers.

Adding:

```
- name: Update sudoers
  become: yes
  community.general.sudoers:
    name: ansible-do-as-mastodon
    state: present
    user: ansible
    runas: mastodon
    commands: ALL
```

resolved the issue